# Java 8 Functional Programming - Passing function along with its argument

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

I have a question on Java 8 Functional Programming. I am trying to achieve something using functional programming, and need some guidance on how to do it.

My requirement is to wrap every method execution inside timer function which times the method execution. Here's the example of timer function and 2 functions I need to time.

```
timerMethod(String timerName, Function func){
  timer.start(timerName)
  func.apply()
  timer.stop()
}

functionA(String arg1, String arg2)

functionB(int arg1, intArg2, String ...arg3)
```

I am trying to pass `functionA` & `functionB` to `timerMethod`, but `functionA` & `functionB` expects different number & type of arguments for execution.

Any ideas how can I achieve it.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hold onto the arguments and then pass them at the last moment. Pass them immediately, but delay calling the function by wrapping it with another function:

```
Producer<?> f1 =
    () -> functionA(arg1, arg2);

Producer<?> f2 =
    () -> functionB(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Here, I'm wrapping each function call in a lambda (`() ->...`) that takes 0 arguments. Then, just call them later with no arguments:

```
f1() 
f2()
```

This forms a closure over the arguments that you supplied in the lambda, which allows you to use the variables later, even though normally they would have been GC'd for going out of scope.

Note, I have a `?` as the type of the `Producer` since I don't know what type your functions return. Change the `?` to the return type of each function.

Answer (score 4):

you should separate it into two things by [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to make your code easy to use and maintaining. one is **timing**, another is **invoking**, for example:

```
//                                       v--- invoking occurs in request-time
R1 result1 = timerMethod("functionA", () -> functionA("foo", "bar"));
R2 result2 = timerMethod("functionB", () -> functionB(1, 2, "foo", "bar"));


// the timerMethod only calculate the timing-cost
<T> T timerMethod(String timerName, Supplier<T> func) {
    timer.start(timerName);
    try {
        return func.get();
    } finally {
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

**IF** you want to return a functional interface rather than the result of that method, you can done it as below:

```
Supplier<R1> timingFunctionA =timerMethod("A", ()-> functionA("foo", "bar"));
Supplier<R2> timingFunctionB =timerMethod("B", ()-> functionB(1, 2, "foo", "bar"));


<T> Supplier<T> timerMethod(String timerName, Supplier<T> func) {
    //      v--- calculate the timing-cost when the wrapper function is invoked
    return () -> {
        timer.start(timerName);
        try {
            return func.get();
        } finally {
            timer.stop();
        }
    };
}
```

### Notes

**IF** the return type of all of your functions is `void`, you can replacing `Supplier` with `Runnable` and then make the `timerMethod`'s return type to `void` & remove `return` keyword from `timerMethod`.

**IF** some of your functions will be throws a checked exception, you can replacing `Supplier` with `Callable` & invoke `Callable#call` instead.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks !!

Comment: @user2751441 Not at all. I'm learning too when I answer your qeustion, :)

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

The other answers show how to use a closure to capture the arguments of your function, no matter its number. This is a nice approach and it's very useful, **if you know the arguments in advance**, so that they can be captured.

Here I'd like to show two other approaches that don't require you to know the arguments in advance...

If you think it in an abstract way, there are no such things as functions with multiple arguments. Functions either receive one set of values (aka a *tuple*), or they receive one single argument and return another function that receives another single argument, which in turn returns another one-argument function that returns... etc, with the last function of the sequence returning an actual result (aka *currying*).

Methods in Java might have multiple arguments, though. So the challenge is to build functions that always receive one single argument (either by means of tuples or currying), but that actually invoke methods that receive multiple arguments.

---

## Approach #1: Tuples

So the first approach is to use a [`Tuple`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Type_theory) helper class and have your function receive one tuple, either a `Tuple2` or `Tuple3`:

So, the `functionA` of your example might receive *one single* `Tuple2<String, String>` as an argument:

```
Function<Tuple2<String, String>, SomeReturnType> functionA = tuple -> 
    functionA(tuple.getFirst(), tuple.getSecond());
```

And you could invoke it as follows:

```
SomeReturnType resultA = functionA.apply(Tuple2.of("a", "b"));
```

Now, in order to *decorate* the `functionA` with your `timerMethod` method, you'd need to do a few modifications:

```
static <T, R> Function<T, R> timerMethod(
        String timerName, 
        Function<? super T, ? extends R> func){
    return t -> {
        timer.start(timerName);
        R result = func.apply(t);
        timer.stop();
        return result;
    };
}
```

Please note that you should use a `try/finally` block to make your code more robust, as shown in [holi-java's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106042/1876620).

Here's how you might use your `timerMethod` method for `functionA`:

```
Function<Tuple2<String, String>, SomeReturnType> timedFunctionA = timerMethod(
    "timerA", 
    tuple -> functionA(tuple.getFirst(), tuple.getSecond());
```

And you can invoke `timedFunctionA` as any other function, passing it the arguments *now*, at invocation time:

```
SomeReturnType resultA = timedFunctionA.apply(Tuple2.of("a", "b"));
```

You can take a similar approach with the `functionB` of your example, except that you'd need to use a `Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String[]>` for the argument (taking care of the varargs arguments).

The downside of this approach is that you need to create many `Tuple` classes, i.e. `Tuple2`, `Tuple3`, `Tuple4`, etc, because Java lacks built-in support for tuples.

---

## Approach #2: Currying

The other approach is to use a technique called [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), i.e. functions that accept one single argument and return another function that accepts another single argument, etc, with the last function of the sequence returning the actual result.

Here's how to create a currified function for your 2-argument method `functionA`:

```
Function<String, Function<String, SomeReturnType>> currifiedFunctionA =
    arg1 -> arg2 -> functionA(arg1, arg2);
```

Invoke it as follows:

```
SomeReturnType result = currifiedFunctionA.apply("a").apply("b");
```

If you want to *decorate* `currifiedFunctionA` with the `timerMethod` method defined above, you can do as follows:

```
Function<String, Function<String, SomeReturnType>> timedCurrifiedFunctionA =
    arg1 -> timerMethod("timerCurryA", arg2 -> functionA(arg1, arg2));
```

Then, invoke `timedCurrifiedFunctionA` exactly as you'd do with any currified function:

```
SomeReturnType result = timedCurrifiedFunctionA.apply("a").apply("b");
```

*Please note that you only need to decorate the last function of the sequence, i.e. the one that makes the actual call to the method, which is what we want to measure.*

For the method `functionB` of your example, you can take a similar approach, except that the type of the currified function would now be:

```
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<String[], SomeResultType>>>
```

which is quite cumbersome, to say the least. So this is the downside of currified functions in Java: the syntax to express their type. On the other hand, currified functions are very handy to work with and allow you to apply several functional programming techniques without needing to write helper classes.

Comment: the answer is already closed. :(. you write it more detailed. up!!